# Why checkboxes are not visible in spring boot framework?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I wrote the following code in html

```
<form>
    <textarea class="heighttext" type="text"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="your-group" value="unit-in-group" />Unit-in-group
</form>
```

But the problem is that when I run the application it just shows text "Unit-in-group" and the checkbox is invisible. Can anyone tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code should be

```
<form>
<textarea class="heighttext" type="text"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="your-group" value="unit-in-group">Unit-in-group
</form>
```

Comment: HTML in spring boot is XML compliant. It should have closing tag. Therefore we cannot let the input tag without closing it.